# Двойные круглые скобки - что означают?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Помогите пожалуйста понять синтаксис выражения на Javascript в React (Mobx) :

```
export default function(Component){
    return inject('stores')(observer(Component));
}
```

Что написано по смыслу я понимаю, а синтаксис не понятен.
Как я понял:
inject('stores') - функция с параметром 'stores'

Что тогда означают (observer(Component)) ?

Comment: Вызов функции. `inject('stores')` возвращает функцию, потом она вызывается с параметром `observer(Component)`

Answer (score 5):

Функция может возвращать функцию, которую можно вызвать, она вернет функцию, которая при вызове вернет функцию...

```js
function sum(a) {
  const add = function(b) {
    if (b !== undefined) {
      a = a + b;
      return add;
    }
    return a;
  }
  return add;
}

console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)(4)()) //10
```

Answer (score 2):

Понятнее станет, если разнести все вызовы функций по переменным:

```
export default function(Component){
    var stores = inject('stores');
    var componentObserver = observer(Component);
    return stores(componentObserver);
    // return inject('stores')(observer(Component));
}
```